# Normalize table with 2 attributes only

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

WhenI have a table with 2 attributes only and without dependenceno dependencies. Can I split them as below? Is it in 1NF? Thanks in advance!!!! 
Original table:

Staff,Skill
A,Cleaning
A,Repairing
A,Coloring
B,Repairing
B,Cleaning
B,Polishing

Split into:
[Staffs] 
Staffs (PK) 
A 
B

[Skills]
skill (PK)
Cleaning
 
Coloring
 
Repairing 
Polishing 

[Staff_Skill] (bridge) 
Staff(PK)(FK),Skill(PK)(FK)
Staff,Skill
A,Cleaning
A,Repairing
A,Coloring
B,Repairing
B,Cleaning
B,Polishing

**Edit version:**
Actually my tables are as below. Are they logical? Thanks in advance!!!

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCR1Z.jpg)
**Edit 2 **
I try my best to explain clearly
[Table Question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XI3B.jpg)

Comment: Please give a reference to your use of "dependency", "1NF" and "normalize", and why you think this decomposition is appropriate. (Various things in your question suggest that you really don't understand normalization.)

Comment: I just change the content. I post an image of my "tables", Are they logical? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normalization is a process with many steps and technical notions. You haven't given the relevant info for somene to normalize. (FDs & JDs.) The fact that you haven't given it suggests that you don't even know the basics of normalization. You need to tell us what you did and why, with a reference to what process/notions you are using, so that your question becomes specific, about whether those are in error. Otherwise you are asking for a section/chapter/tutorial/lecture on normalization, which is too broad a question.

Comment: Please explain this diagram. And what is your question?? What table is being normalized to what other tables with what notion of "normalization" under what constraints? PS It is helpful to have the info of this image but please do not use images when you can cut and paste text. Eg you can give table headings, keys & FKs in a few lines & you can show example data as tables formatted as code. Please read [ask]. PPS "Are they logical" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Please do not drastically change the content of your question after it has been answered. Please edit your question to clarify or else ask a new question.

Comment: sorry for change the content, cause this is the first time I use the stackoverflow.com. A bit difficult for me to post the table. Let me change it back now.

Comment: 1. Your addition of the PKs & FKs to your original question doesn't change anything in my original answer. 2. Please post a *different question* with your "edit version". 3. Please address my comments & the on-hold comment. 4. What are your questions???

Comment: Thanks a lot Philipxy, stackoverflow.com doesn't let me ask question again before tomorrow. I try my best to explain it at the "Table Quesion 2" image. I know its hard to understand my explanation since I don't know how to ask this question clearly. By the way, thanks a lot :) <br>
I hope I can find some good and detail example of Normalization at the web. Sorry for bothering :(

Comment: I will look for a fresh question with your "edit 2". My answer's PS applies to it. Because (according to your example data) you want to "record that there are staff or skills regardless of whether there are any current pairings of those".

Comment: thanks a lot, Philipxy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization replaces a relation by other ones that join back to it. This is to get rid of problematic FDs (functional dependencies) and JDs (join dependencies). If a relation, like this one, is not subject to any non-trivial FDs then it is in BCNF and normalization theory doesn't suggest decomposition. This relation also isn't subject to any non-trivial JDs (it isn't the join of any set of projections of it unless that set contains the original relation), so it is in 5NF and normalization theory doesn't suggest any decomposition. On the other hand, you *can* decompose it into those three components/projections (per a certain trivial JD) because they do always join back to the original--unhelpfully, since one of them *is* the original. Since you have decomposed it (and not distinguished between "no FDs" and "no trivial FDs", and not distinguished between "should" vs "can" decompose, and not distinguished between FDs & JDs, and not clarified "normalize", and you don't understand "1NF"), you need to learn what normalization is, from a college/university textbook/course.

PS If you want to introduce Staffs & Skills so that you can record that there are staff or skills regardless of whether there are any current pairings of those, then that is not suggested by normalization but by your noticing that *your original 1-table design can't record everything you are interested in*. (In that case the two new tables are not always projections of the original, so they can't have been introduced by normalization.)